# Matrix.utils merge.Matrix and merge different results

Tags: r, matrix

I am very confused by the R package `Matrix.utils` and its implementation of `merge.Matrix()`.  I want to merge two matrices with 0 common values, but merge common column names and fill the rest with zeros.

The results are inconsistent and sensitive to whether `merge()` or `merge.Matrix()` is specified.  I expected this to be similar to the `dplyr::join()` function but this is not true.

Simulating the data I plan to use:

```
mtx.x <- sample(1:100, 100) ; mtx.x <- matrix(mtx.x, nrow = 10)
mtx.y <- sample(1:100, 100) ; mtx.y <- matrix(mtx.y, nrow = 10)
 
colnames(mtx.x) <- letters[1:10] ; colnames(mtx.y) <- letters[6:15]

mtx.x ; mtx.y

       a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j
 [1,]  82 61 76 36 27 67 85 38 29 87
 [2,]  83 89 43 70 81 30 35 17 39 95
 [3,]   1 75 69 54 66  3 10 47 93 73
 [4,]  52 98 26 88 51 64 31 72 13 92
 [5,]  44 74 86  9 63 58 50 56  6 49
 [6,]  24 16 77 12 55 97 18 45 14 40
 [7,]  11  5 79 94  2 80 37 15 41 42
 [8,] 100 84 65 59 34 62 53 60 99 28
 [9,]  19 78  8 25 96 21 90 46 68 71
[10,]  32 20  7  4 57 91 22 48 33 23
       f  g  h  i  j   k  l  m  n  o
 [1,] 24 22  8 94 89   7 50 93 40  4
 [2,] 63 80 32 44 64  83 16 96 46 47
 [3,] 85 30 81 95 23  91 19 92 99 52
 [4,] 21 55 61 58 27  76 67 65 37 14
 [5,]  9 66 12  2 41  11 56 84 87 39
 [6,] 18 57 88  3 68 100 74 62 82 25
 [7,] 70 90 43 54 72  86 69 20 29 51
 [8,]  1 59 60 45 79  75 15  5 73 10
 [9,] 38 28 26 17 53  36 97 13 77 49
[10,]  6 71 98 35 42  31 78 33 48 34
```

Case 1: `merge()` with `all.x`/`all.y` set to `TRUE` does what I want

```
merge(x = mtx.x, y = mtx.y, 
      all.x = T, all.y = T) 

    f  g  h  i  j   a  b  c  d  e   k  l  m  n  o
1   1 59 60 45 79  NA NA NA NA NA  75 15  5 73 10
2   3 10 47 93 73   1 75 69 54 66  NA NA NA NA NA
3   6 71 98 35 42  NA NA NA NA NA  31 78 33 48 34
4   9 66 12  2 41  NA NA NA NA NA  11 56 84 87 39
5  18 57 88  3 68  NA NA NA NA NA 100 74 62 82 25
6  21 55 61 58 27  NA NA NA NA NA  76 67 65 37 14
7  21 90 46 68 71  19 78  8 25 96  NA NA NA NA NA
8  24 22  8 94 89  NA NA NA NA NA   7 50 93 40  4
9  30 35 17 39 95  83 89 43 70 81  NA NA NA NA NA
10 38 28 26 17 53  NA NA NA NA NA  36 97 13 77 49
11 58 50 56  6 49  44 74 86  9 63  NA NA NA NA NA
12 62 53 60 99 28 100 84 65 59 34  NA NA NA NA NA
13 63 80 32 44 64  NA NA NA NA NA  83 16 96 46 47
14 64 31 72 13 92  52 98 26 88 51  NA NA NA NA NA
15 67 85 38 29 87  82 61 76 36 27  NA NA NA NA NA
16 70 90 43 54 72  NA NA NA NA NA  86 69 20 29 51
17 80 37 15 41 42  11  5 79 94  2  NA NA NA NA NA
18 85 30 81 95 23  NA NA NA NA NA  91 19 92 99 52
19 91 22 48 33 23  32 20  7  4 57  NA NA NA NA NA
20 97 18 45 14 40  24 16 77 12 55  NA NA NA NA NA
```

Case 2: `merge.Matrix()` with same arguments wants me to specify `by.x`/`by.y`

```
merge.Matrix(x = mtx.x, y = mtx.y, 
             all.x = T, all.y = T)
Error in grr::matches(by.x, by.y, all.x, all.y, nomatch = NULL) : 
  argument "by.x" is missing, with no default
```

Case 3: specifying `by.x`/`by.y` as respective column names does not merge common columns. also, no idea why its offsetting the matrices by 5 and not 10, the matrices have no common values.

```
merge.Matrix(x = mtx.x, y = mtx.y, 
             all.x = T, all.y = T,
             by.x = colnames(mtx.x), by.y = colnames(mtx.y))

         a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j y.f y.g y.h y.i y.j   k  l  m  n  o
        82 61 76 36 27 67 85 38 29 87  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA NA NA NA NA
        83 89 43 70 81 30 35 17 39 95  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA NA NA NA NA
         1 75 69 54 66  3 10 47 93 73  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA NA NA NA NA
        52 98 26 88 51 64 31 72 13 92  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA NA NA NA NA
        44 74 86  9 63 58 50 56  6 49  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA NA NA NA NA
        24 16 77 12 55 97 18 45 14 40  24  22   8  94  89   7 50 93 40  4
        11  5 79 94  2 80 37 15 41 42  63  80  32  44  64  83 16 96 46 47
       100 84 65 59 34 62 53 60 99 28  85  30  81  95  23  91 19 92 99 52
        19 78  8 25 96 21 90 46 68 71  21  55  61  58  27  76 67 65 37 14
        32 20  7  4 57 91 22 48 33 23   9  66  12   2  41  11 56 84 87 39
fill.x  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  18  57  88   3  68 100 74 62 82 25
fill.x  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  70  90  43  54  72  86 69 20 29 51
fill.x  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA   1  59  60  45  79  75 15  5 73 10
fill.x  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  38  28  26  17  53  36 97 13 77 49
fill.x  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA   6  71  98  35  42  31 78 33 48 34
```

Case 4: `by.x`/`by.y` specified as common column names, `all.x`/`all.y` set to `TRUE` and `fill.x`/`fill.y` set to 0 does not do a full join as the documentation claims

```
common <- intersect(colnames(mtx.x), colnames(mtx.y))
merge.Matrix(x = mtx.x, y = mtx.y, 
             all.x = T, all.y = T,
             by.x = common, by.y = common)
  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j y.f y.g y.h y.i y.j  k  l  m  n  o
 82 61 76 36 27 67 85 38 29 87  24  22   8  94  89  7 50 93 40  4
 83 89 43 70 81 30 35 17 39 95  63  80  32  44  64 83 16 96 46 47
  1 75 69 54 66  3 10 47 93 73  85  30  81  95  23 91 19 92 99 52
 52 98 26 88 51 64 31 72 13 92  21  55  61  58  27 76 67 65 37 14
 44 74 86  9 63 58 50 56  6 49   9  66  12   2  41 11 56 84 87 39
```